# Sequelize hasMany add array of id's

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, has-many

This is my model definition:

```
var Customer = sequelize.define('Customer', {
    name: Sequelize.STRING
});

var Route = sequelize.define('Route', {
    name: Sequelize.STRING,
});

Customer.belongsTo(Route);
Route.hasMany(Customer);
```

I have customers with id 1 and 2. When i run this query, routeId is not added to customer collection

```
Route
  .create({ name: 'route1', customers: [1,2] })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the association in your create method in order to add it.

```
Route
  .create({ 
     name: 'route1', 
     customers: [{ name: "customer1" }, { name: "customer2" }] 
  }, { 
     include: [ Customer ] 
  });
```

This will CREATE the customers in your table.

If you want to add a route that is associated with two existing customers, you need to take a different approach.

```
Route.create( { name: "route1" } )
     .then( route => route.addCustomers( [ 1, 2 ] ) )
```